# WAMP 2.2 and Subversion 1.7.5., how does it work?

Tags: svn, wamp

So i have been working with WAMP for a long time and recently decided to include Subversion and try to connect it with the Apache server installed with WAMP. I have been running over about 6 to 8 guides so far of which almost all of them tell me the same deal.

Copy the `mod_dav.so` files and such to the module directory of the Apache installation, then copy the `intl3_svn.dll` and `libdb48.dll` files to the `/bin` folder of Apache HTTP Server etc. Change the `httpd.conf` file for Apache to include the new modules as well as a new directory definition for SVN things.

But every single guide seems to mention different `mod_dav.so` files and different `.dll` files. To top it off, when i got the files copied every single time i restart Apache it won't work. It simply refuses to work with the changes to the `httpd.conf` file even though I literally copied it from the guides.

Is there anyone that has experience with installing subversion 1.7.5. with WAMP server 2.2 that could help me out?

EDIT:

The error log of the Apache Server actually doesn't really say anything at all.

I added the following lines to the list of loaded modules in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

The dav_module already existed in the standard httpd.conf file and i only had to enable it by removing the '#' tag.

Comment: Post the apache configuration you have added for SVN.  If it fails to start, look in the error_log to see what went wrong.

Comment: Are you just doing this for some learning / education purpose? If so, it's OK. :)

However if you just need to have a working instance of Apache Subversion on a Windows machine -- install the standard edition VisualSVN Server http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Comment: It is indeed intended as abit of self education on getting this to work without visualSVN.

Comment: @Björn very strange that nothing gets logged into Apache log. What is the logging level on your instance? Try setting it to 'Debug' error level and see what get's logged then. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this article](http://shareurthoughtss.blogspot.in/2012/08/svn-server-configuration-on-wamp-server.html) will guide you in a proper way of installing subversion on WAMP server.

If it works don't forgot to promote it to correct answer.. So it may help others.